# PDO statement may be incorrect

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the below PDO statement, I am trying to find if there is row that matches the statement and return 1 if true, then echo "There was a match". For some reason it keeps returning false even though my database clearly has a match on line 24. I am hoping someone can spot the error for me.

The PDO statement:

```
<?php

$employeeID = 1;
$dateToday = "01/12/13";

try{
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=timecard', 'username', 'password');
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM timeRecords WHERE `timeOut`= 'NULL' AND `employeeID`= :employeeID AND `date`= :dateToday");

    $stmt->execute(array(':employeeID' => $employeeID, ':dateToday' => $dateToday));
    } catch(PDOException $e){
        echo'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

if($stmt->fetchColumn() > 0){
    echo "There was a match!";
} else {
    echo "There was no Match";
}

?>
```

The database:

```
+----+------------+----------+------------------+---------------------+-----------+------------+-----------+------------------+
| id | employeeID | date     | timeIn           | jobDescription      | equipType | unitNumber | unitHours | timeOut          |
+----+------------+----------+------------------+---------------------+-----------+------------+-----------+------------------+
|  1 |       NULL | NULL     | 01/06/13 7:16 pm |                     |           | NULL       |      NULL | 01/06/13 8:57 pm |
|  2 |       NULL | NULL     |                  |                     |           | NULL       |      NULL | 01/06/13 7:17 pm |
|  3 |       NULL | NULL     | 01/06/13 8:43 pm |                     |           | NULL       |      NULL | NULL             |
|  4 |       NULL | NULL     | 2:12 am          |                     |           | NULL       |      NULL | 12:47 pm         |
|  5 |       NULL | NULL     | 8:33 pm          |                     |           | NULL       |      NULL | NULL             |
| 17 |       NULL | NULL     | 2:32 pm          |                     |           | NULL       |      NULL | NULL             |
| 18 |       NULL | 01/12/13 | 2:33 pm          |                     |           | NULL       |      NULL | 5:07 pm          |
| 19 |       NULL | 01/12/13 | 2:37 pm          |                     |           | NULL       |      NULL | 5:07 pm          |
| 20 |       NULL | 01/12/13 | 5:07 pm          |                     |           | NULL       |      NULL | 5:07 pm          |
| 21 |          1 | 01/12/13 | 5:31 pm          | Worked in Jefferson | Excavator | 01E        |      8182 | 5:37 pm          |
| 22 |       NULL | NULL     |                  | Worked in Jefferson | Excavator | 01E        |      8932 | NULL             |
| 23 |       NULL | 01/12/13 | 7:10 pm          |                     |           | NULL       |      NULL | NULL             |
| 24 |          1 | 01/12/13 | 7:11 pm          |                     |           | NULL       |      NULL | NULL             |
+----+------------+----------+------------------+---------------------+-----------+------------+-----------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to change = 'null' because its looking for string 'NULL' and not NULL

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM timeRecords WHERE `timeOut` IS NULL AND `employeeID`= :employeeID AND `date`= :dateToday");
```

Also you might want to try:

```
if($stmt->rowCount()){
    echo "There was a match!";
}else{
    echo "There was no Match";
}
```